# 100 Instance of VlcControl

Tags: wpf, video-streaming, vlc

I'm noob to Vlc.DotNet (Wpf)!
I want to develop a CCTV application that support 100 camera live view in one page!
I have a 10x10 grid that shows videos in cells.

[Run-time Screenshot](http://gigacycle.persiangig.com/image/slowPlaying.jpg)

The problem is that the application slows down and goes to halt after 36 tiles of videos.

here is my test :

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="vlc_stream_test.videoGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Wpf="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf" Title="Video Lan Grid" Height="500" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid Name="root" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

code behind :

```
try
{
   VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath = CommonStrings.LIBVLC_DLLS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;
   VlcContext.LibVlcPluginsPath = CommonStrings.PLUGINS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;
}
catch
{
   VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath = CommonStrings.LIBVLC_DLLS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_X86;
   VlcContext.LibVlcPluginsPath = CommonStrings.PLUGINS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_X86;
}
VlcContext.StartupOptions.IgnoreConfig = true;
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.LogInFile = false;
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.ShowLoggerConsole = false;
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.Verbosity = VlcLogVerbosities.None;
Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--network-caching=1000");
Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--no-skip-frames");
Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--no-video-title");
Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--live-caching=10000");
VlcContext.Initialize();
InitializeComponent();
root.Background = Brushes.DarkGreen;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
     {
      var visBrush = new VisualBrush() { Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill };
      Grid g = new Grid() {Background = visBrush, Margin = new Thickness(1) };

      g.PreviewMouseDown += (sender, e) =>
      {
           VlcControl vlc = new VlcControl() { Media = new LocationMedia("file:///C:/Users/Public/Videos/wildlife.wmv") };
           Binding binding = new Binding("VideoSource") { Source = vlc };
           var imgBox = new Image();
           imgBox.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, binding);
           visBrush.Visual = imgBox;
       };
       root.Children.Add(g);
       Grid.SetColumn(g, j);
      Grid.SetRow(g, i);
  }
```

The video specification that I used :

Resolution : 128x96

bitRate : 72 kb/s

Audio : none

video format : wmv1

[Here is the video (298.67 KB)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1h27hafyi9wt1u4/Wildlife.wmv?dl=0)

I need a solution that solve my problem...
thanks.

Comment: You might need to process the video flux in order to "mix" them.

Comment: So how can I control (play/pause separately) them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com) to show 100 different video streams in the one page. AForge is more faster & lighter than VLC!

To using Aforge.Net in wpf check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779198/1551735)!