# WPF - How to change button's image programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, aforge

I'm creating a wpf application and implementing usb webcam to my Project using aforge. In my `CameraWindow` I have an `Image` control where I'm displaying lastest captured image from my usb webcam. [Here is the sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006055/implementing-a-webcam-on-a-wpf-app-using-aforge-net)

In my thirt window (`AllCapturedImages`) I have an `Image` control and in it
I'm displaying latest captured image from usb webcam. This happens using `Action()` in my `CameraWindow`.

```
<Image x:Name="newlyAddedImage" Margin="10,10,230,10"/>

public Action<BitmapImage> newlyCapturedImage;
if (newlyCapturedImage != null)
{
    newlyCapturedImage(CapturedImages.Last());
}
```

In the same window (`AllCapturedImages`) I have three more `Image` controls
Here is one of them:

```
<Button x:Name="PreviewButton1" Margin="577,10,25,404">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image x:Name="SPPreviewImage1"></Image>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

and what I want is change/update these `Image`'s `Source` every time I capture an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the `Button`'s `ControlTemplate` like this:

```
<Button x:Name="PreviewButton1" Margin="577,10,25,404">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

...you could simply set its `Content` property to an `Image` element:

```
var bitmapImage = CapturedImages.Last();
PreviewButton1.Content = new Image() { Source = bitmapImage };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `<Image x:Name="newlyAddedImage" Margin="10,10,230,10"/>` this is my `Image` control where I'm able to display lastest captured image right now. I have tested your answer to my second `Image` control but it is not diplaying anything :/

Comment: What if you temporarilt try to set the Content of the Button to a TextBlock?: PreviewButton1.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "TEST" }; Do you see the text?

Comment: Nothing happens. I mean I dont see the text

Comment: What if you remove the <Button.Template> part altogether. Do you even see the Button?

Comment: Yes I see the button when I removed `<Button.Template>` and it started working! :D I mean `PreviewButton1.Content = new Image() { Source = newImage };` I can see the latest captured image in my second `Image` control wtf...

Comment: You need to set the TargetType property of the ControlTemplate. I edited my answer.